# Есть ли в этом предложении приложение?

Tags: синтаксис, приложение

**Вот и Иртыш — могучая сибирская река.**
Скажите, пожалуйста, в этом предложении "могучая сибирская река" — это обособленное приложение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, в данном случае "могучая сибирская река" будет обособленным приложением. Обособляется оно посредством тире, так как тире в данном случае можно заменить словами "а именно". Вдобавок данное приложение стоит в конце предложения и в данном контексте имеет самостоятельный оттенок.